# Download a single image from Google Street View

Tags: shell, wget, download, url

I just found that we can see Google Street View images from the following link:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x640&location=38.3810257,-89.486167&heading=0
(where heading is the rotation). 
My question is that. How can I download that image from my terminal?

I tried with:

```
wget https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x640&location=38.3810257,-89.486167&heading=0
```

But it creates a file named "wget-log" and its content says ERROR 400: Bad Request.
Thank you

Comment: did you singe quote url ? because `&` has a special meaning in  most shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I need to quote the url because of &:

```
wget "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x640&location=38.3810257,-89.486167&heading=0" -O downloaded.jpg
```